# VLOOKUP ERROR. Works for some cells, does not work on others

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

So, I have a vlookup formula

=VLOOKUP(A2, Vouchers!E:K, 7, FALSE)

and it's been copied down the table and has been working great.  But suddenly, it has stopped working for new rows.
I double checked to make sure that the value in column A is actually present in the reference sheet, but it's still returning a #N/A

The weird part is that if I copy and paste the referenced value, suddenly the formula works again.

So, for example, in A140, I have 8063234, and it returns the correct value. But in column A141, I also have 8063234, but it returns #N/A.

I found a reddit post from 4 years ago that had a similar situation.  They suggested that the issue might be regarding the formatting (e.g. one is formatted as text), but both columns are formatted as text.  When I changed the formatting in all columns to general, the error persists.

[VLOOKUP ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBxKI.png)
[Reference table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYKcJ.png)

Comment: Seems like Text Formatted. Unless you have aligned them on left. In Excel Numbers are right aligned while texts are left aligned by default

Comment: I prefer using this way: `=VLOOKUP(A2&"", Vouchers!E:K, 7, FALSE)`

Comment: Both columns (reference sheet and original sheet) are formatted as text, because these are invoice numbers that sometimes have preceding zeros. but even when I format everything as number or everything as general, the error persists.  furthermore, i've now double checked alignment, and it matches in all the columns.

Comment: How are you entering those `Invoices` manually or are you pasting from any applications like `SQL` or `SAP` etc?

Comment: I'm entering the invoice values manually.  and i tried your formula, and surprisingly, it returned even more #N/As than my original formula.

Comment: So what about the source file, does that have any white spaces or non breaking characters. Using the formula I have suggested it should be working, oh I missed the quotes in the array; `=VLOOKUP(A2&"", Vouchers!E:K&"", 7, FALSE)`

Comment: I just checked, and it doesn't have any.  I think it has to be some formatting issue that I can't figure out.

So in my vlookup sheet, I can have the same value in two rows, and it only work on one of the rows.  If I copy past the value that returns the error into the other sheet where it's pulling the data, then it works, but the other value that seems to be working stops working (sorry if I'm explaining that poorly.)  But all values in all sheets were manually entered to begin with.  So I have no idea where this formatting issue is.  And when I do format painter, it changes nothing.

Comment: omg, the formula =VLOOKUP(A2&"", Vouchers!E:K&"", 7, FALSE) has fixed the error.  it seems to be working perfectly now.  I did not know about that other way to use the formula.  I am so relieved!

Thank you!

Comment: please do! thanks again!

Comment: Posted in the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as commented above the following formula should work if the **`lookup_value`** is formatted as `text` or not like wise the **`table_array`**. And OP has confirmed as well, found the same is `working` accordingly hence posting it:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2&"", Vouchers!E:K&"", 7, FALSE)
```

---

The **`&""`** concats an **`empty string`** to the **`lookup_value`**, this ensures that `Excel` treats the **`lookup_value`** as text as well as in the **`table_array`**.

---

Alternatively using `XLOOKUP()` if applicable:

```
=XLOOKUP(A2&"", Vouchers!E:E&"", Vouchers!K:K&"", "")
```

---